# Como executar macro com projeto bloqueado?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba, password

Olá, tenho uma planilha cujo projeto tem uma senha, porem quero que as macros funcionem e se o usuário tentar entrar nas macros ele terá que por a senha (que eu coloquei no projeto).

Eu coloquei um código que desbloqueia a planilha ao entrar, ele é assim:

```
Option Explicit

Private Const PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE = &H40

Private Declare PtrSafe Sub MoveMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As LongPtr, Source As LongPtr, ByVal Length As LongPtr)

Private Declare PtrSafe Function VirtualProtect Lib "kernel32" (lpAddress As LongPtr, ByVal dwSize As LongPtr, ByVal flNewProtect As LongPtr, lpflOldProtect As LongPtr) As LongPtr

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetModuleHandleA Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpModuleName As String) As LongPtr

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetProcAddress Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hModule As LongPtr, ByVal lpProcName As String) As LongPtr

Private Declare PtrSafe Function DialogBoxParam Lib "user32" Alias "DialogBoxParamA" (ByVal hInstance As LongPtr, ByVal pTemplateName As LongPtr, ByVal hWndParent As LongPtr, ByVal lpDialogFunc As LongPtr, ByVal dwInitParam As LongPtr) As Integer

Dim HookBytes(0 To 5) As Byte
Dim OriginBytes(0 To 5) As Byte
Dim pFunc As LongPtr
Dim Flag As Boolean

Private Function GetPtr(ByVal Value As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    GetPtr = Value
End Function

Public Sub RecoverBytes()

    If Flag Then MoveMemory ByVal pFunc, ByVal VarPtr(OriginBytes(0)), 6

End Sub

Public Function Hook() As Boolean
    Dim TmpBytes(0 To 5) As Byte
    Dim p As LongPtr
    Dim OriginProtect As LongPtr

    Hook = False

    pFunc = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("user32.dll"), "DialogBoxParamA")


    If VirtualProtect(ByVal pFunc, 6, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, OriginProtect) <> 0 Then

        MoveMemory ByVal VarPtr(TmpBytes(0)), ByVal pFunc, 6

        If TmpBytes(0) <> &H68 Then

            MoveMemory ByVal VarPtr(OriginBytes(0)), ByVal pFunc, 6

            p = GetPtr(AddressOf MyDialogBoxParam)

            HookBytes(0) = &H68
            MoveMemory ByVal VarPtr(HookBytes(1)), ByVal VarPtr(p), 4
            HookBytes(5) = &HC3

            MoveMemory ByVal pFunc, ByVal VarPtr(HookBytes(0)), 6
            Flag = True
            Hook = True

        End If

    End If

End Function

Private Function MyDialogBoxParam(ByVal hInstance As LongPtr, ByVal pTemplateName As LongPtr, ByVal hWndParent As LongPtr, ByVal lpDialogFunc As LongPtr, ByVal dwInitParam As LongPtr) As Integer

    If pTemplateName = 4070 Then
        MyDialogBoxParam = 1
    Else
        RecoverBytes
        MyDialogBoxParam = DialogBoxParam(hInstance, pTemplateName, hWndParent, lpDialogFunc, dwInitParam)
        Hook
    End If
End Function
```

Esse código executa quando abre a planilha (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026483/is-there-a-way-to-crack-the-password-on-an-excel-vba-project?rq=1), porem quando vou executar outra macro, o Excel aponta que a planilha está bloqueada e não irá executar.

Alguém teria uma macro que me auxiliasse nisso? Talvez KeyCode. Ou um UserForm.

Esse é o erro que acontece:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acho que não entendi bem... normalmente protege-se o código das macros e não sua execução. Quando coloca uma senha no código para o usuário não conseguir ver o projeto vba isso não impede a execução da macro. O que deve estar impedindo a execução é que sua planilha está bloqueada, não?

Comment: Exatamente isso que deveria acontecer, mas quando eu executo por exemplo o `Before Save` ele aponta um erro. Editei minha pergunta e coloquei o erro, da uma olhada.

Comment: Mas por que está querendo *craquear* sua própria planilha? Confesso que está confuso isso ai... Creio que não precisa desse código ai em sua própria planilha.

Comment: Foi só uma tentativa de desbloquear e bloquear novamente. O grande problema esta no não funcionamento do código.

Comment: Irmão... sugiro tentar fazer tudo rodar sem bloquear nada, retire todo que possui de bloqueio, se tudo estiver funcionando, comece a pensar no que precisa bloquear... se for apenas o código vba não precisará de nenhum código para isso... somente vá nas configurações e coloque sua senha.

Comment: Essa é a questão kk. Eu só bloquiei o código VBA

Comment: e parou de funcionar?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60850/discussion-between-evert-and-leandro-felipe-moreira).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Então, conversando com @Evert, mandei minha planilha para ele. Descobrimos que havia sim uma macro que alterava o código, então realmente havia um erro.

Agora a planilha esta funcionando perfeitamente.